# Cairo won't load in RStudio on Mac

Tags: r, graphics, cairo

When I run

```
library(Cairo)
```

I get the error

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Cairo’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Cairo', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so, 6): Symbol not found: _inflateValidate
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so
```

I already downloaded Cairo and it shows up in my packages. I tried redownloading XQuartz and restarting my computer, but it didn't fix the issue. I'm new to R and very lost as to how to fix it. Where should I go from here? Thanks!!

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: I'm using Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Well, i'm not sure if it's problem but the message does say that Cairo was "was built for Mac OS X 10.13". You could try installing the package from source rather than using the precompiled version with `install.packages("Cairo", type="source")` but that assumes you've got Xcode all set up to compile things. And I'm not really 100% sure that's the answer. It is interested that R says it requires 10.13 for version R 4.0. I'm surprised it's running on 10.12.6.

Comment: I updated to Sierra and it fixed the issue! Thanks for your help! I feel silly for not thinking to do that earlier.